# Poetry and python problems after uninstalling anaconda (Mac OS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, python-poetry

I recently uninstalled anaconda and reinstalled its M1 version as I have been mistakenly using its intel version previously (I followed the [official guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/)).

I have some projects that use poetry that I have previously installed inside a conda environment with `pip install poetry`. I wanted to repeat this process in new conda environment but I get the following error message:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: xattr
  Building wheel for xattr (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for xattr (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/lib_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/lib.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/tool.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      copying xattr/pyxattr_compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/xattr
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/_lib.c'
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      building '_lib' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/build
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312
      clang -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/include/python3.12 -c build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/_lib.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-312/_lib.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xattr
Failed to build xattr
ERROR: Could not build wheels for xattr, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I also get a similar error message when typing `python --version`:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

but when I type `python3 --version` I get:

```
Python 3.12.1
```

Would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using pip within anaconda instead of conda install, as in `conda install -c conda-forge poetry`?

Comment: Not really. I was just following my company's codebase setup doc

Answer (score 0):

The first error says you're missing `xcrun`, try (re)installing xcode by running `xcode-select --install` and see if that resolves it.

Comment: This helped with `pip install poetry` and `python --version`. However I still get the same error message when I execute any `poetry` command

Comment: I'd suggest you edit this question the include only the first (resolved) part and then create another question for the other problem.